# AWS Redshift Leader Node-Only Function with table reference ambiguity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to run queries on INFORMATION_SCHEMA on AWS Redshift. My query works totally fine if i'm running on one database, But running into LEADER_NODE- functions only errors when i'm trying to run the same query on different database.

Please note that both the databases are on the same server host in AWS.

Error: "ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [0A000] [Microsoft][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 0A000] ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

ERROR [01000] INFO:  Function "has_table_privilege(oid,text)" not supported.

ERROR [01000] INFO:  Function "has_column_privilege(oid,smallint,text)" not supported.
".

I understand that there is a concept of LEADER-Node only functions and Compute-Node only functions, but same query on information_schema works if i point to different database on the same server host.

I'm using Azure Data Factory copy data activity to connect to Redshift using unload functionality.